# How to write bash file for establishing a ssh connection

Tags: bash, dictionary, ssh, ssh-keys

I tried to write a bash file for establishing a SSH tunnel from Pi 1 to Pi2. I found several guides and did it according to them - so far so good. Everything is working now if I type the following in the terminal:

```sh
ssh -i .ssh/key_rsa pi@192.168.0.107
```

I tried the same line of code in a bash file, but there appears the following error message: „File or Dictionary not found“

My bash Code:

```sh
#!usr/bin/bash -f

xterm -title “Terminal1“ -hold -e ssh -i “.ssh/key_rsa“ “ pi@192.168.0.107“
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: This question, at least, is using the wrong kind of quotes. You need `"`, not `“`.

Comment: What is the complete error message that you're getting? Don't paraphrase it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it from inside you $HOME where `.ssh/key_rsa` is located?
Perhaps set it to use an absolute path like `$HOME/.ssh/key_rsa`

Comment: ist is located in /home/pi/.ssh

Comment: Ist working now with $HOME/.ssh/key_rsa. THANKS A LOT!